# node_modules folder and Angular2 in an ASP.Net MVC project in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: typescript, angular

I followed the steps in [Angular.io's quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html), except for the Angular component section, to install Angular2 to my new ASP.Net MVC Core project.

By default, it installed the node_modules in a hierarchical fashion and resulted in my web project not being loaded because the file paths are too long. I then flattened it using "npm dedupe".

I am getting a number of "Build: Cannot find name '____'" errors (Map, Set, WeakMap, etc.)

How do I resolve this?

UPDATE

This is what I have in my web project file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">14.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\DNX\Microsoft.DNX.Props" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <ProjectGuid>3775534b-d08c-45f2-8d5a-4a4f6e91edb9</ProjectGuid>
    <RootNamespace>MyProject</RootNamespace>
    <BaseIntermediateOutputPath Condition="'$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)'=='' ">..\..\artifacts\obj\$(MSBuildProjectName)</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
    <OutputPath Condition="'$(OutputPath)'=='' ">..\..\artifacts\bin\$(MSBuildProjectName)\</OutputPath>
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
    <TypeScriptTarget>ES5</TypeScriptTarget>
    <TypeScriptJSXEmit>None</TypeScriptJSXEmit>
    <TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>True</TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>
    <TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>False</TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>
    <TypeScriptModuleKind>CommonJS</TypeScriptModuleKind>
    <TypeScriptRemoveComments>False</TypeScriptRemoveComments>
    <TypeScriptOutFile />
    <TypeScriptModuleResolution>NodeJs</TypeScriptModuleResolution>
    <TypeScriptOutDir />
    <TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>False</TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>
    <TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>True</TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>
    <TypeScriptSourceMap>True</TypeScriptSourceMap>
    <TypeScriptMapRoot />
    <TypeScriptSourceRoot />
    <TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators>True</TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target Name="FixTsBuildConfiguration" BeforeTargets="CompileTypeScript" >
    <PropertyGroup>
      <TypeScriptBuildConfigurations>$(TypeScriptBuildConfigurations.Replace("--moduleResolution NodeJs", "--moduleResolution node"))</TypeScriptBuildConfigurations>
   </PropertyGroup>
  </Target>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DnxInvisibleContent Include="bower.json" />
    <DnxInvisibleContent Include=".bowerrc" />
    <DnxInvisibleContent Include="package.json" />
    <DnxInvisibleFolder Include="wwwroot\bower_components\" />
    <DnxInvisibleFolder Include="wwwroot\node_modules\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\DNX\Microsoft.DNX.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
</Project>
```

Comment: try,  inside `tsconfig.json` change `"target": "es5"` to `"target": "es6"`.

Answer (score 0):

this setup is working for me inside an ASP.NET project...

**tsconfig.json**

```
"compilerOptions": {
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"module": "commonjs",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"noImplicitAny": false,
"removeComments": false,
"sourceMap": true,
"target": "es5",
"outDir": "./dist"
},
"exclude": [
        "node_modules"
      ]
```

**index.html**

```
<script>
//configure system loader
    System.config({
        defaultJSExtensions: true,
        paths: {
            '*': 'node_modules/*',
            'dist/*': 'dist/*'
        }
    });
</script>
```

And make sure that whenever you reference the modules in your typescript file, you use just the name of the package, e.g.

```
import {Component, OnInit, Inject} from 'angular2/core';
```

Comment: And by the way with this setup I wasn't obliged to use npm dedupe and so on. I installed the packages to default location using npm i and it worked fine. Hope it helps.

Comment: I didn't have to do dedupe anymore as I have already excluded the folder from the Visual Studio project.

Comment: It's getting me a number of Duplicate Identifier errors now. I'm still figuring out how to fix it.

Comment: I discovered it is due to my component file having a reference tag. I am figuring out how to make it work without that tag.

Comment: Make sure you don't have the node_modules a part of your project. Typescript is then able to locate them, but if you include the folder in the solution it messes everything up. Then you don't need the reference tags.